# Cycle image caption doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cycle

I've cycle slideshow gallery and I put a caption on my images but there is something wrong why I don't understand..Only my attribute name showing on my caption I don't want to attribute name I want to get attribute value what's wrong with me ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mySlideShow').cycle({
    log: false,
    fx: 'fade',
    slides: ">a",
    caption: '.cycle-caption',
    captionTemplate: "{{data-caption}}",
    pauseOnHover: true,
  });
})
```

```css
.slide-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 790px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.slide-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cycle-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-gallery">
  <div class="mySlideShow">

    <a>
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-caption="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..">
    </a>
    <a>
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-caption="This is my caption....">
    </a>
    <a>
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-caption="bla.....">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not use [data-cycle-title](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption.php#adv-custom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few bugs in the way you were defining your caption.

> Mistake 1-

First of all the **data-caption attribute** in **not supported** to  display caption . After reading the documentation despite of data-caption you can use **data-cycle-title** for the captions.

> Mistake 2-

Since the **selector** is anchor tag **slides: "> a"** in your jquery code,  the captions will work on **anchor** tag not on the **< img >** . So I have added the  **data-cycle-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."** on the anchors.
Also  changes the captiontemplate jquery to this:

```
captionTemplate: "' {{cycleTitle}}'",
```

**Below is the working example . Happy Coding :)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mySlideShow').cycle({
    log: false,
    fx: 'fade',
    slides: "> a",
    caption: '.cycle-caption',
    captionTemplate: "' {{cycleTitle}}'",
    pauseOnHover: true,
  });
})
```

```css
.slide-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 790px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.slide-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cycle-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-gallery">
  <div class="mySlideShow">

    <a data-cycle-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" >
    </a>
    <a data-cycle-title="This is my caption....">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" >
    </a>
    <a data-cycle-title="bla.....">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" >
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `captionTemplate` has to be set to an attribute of the top level element, the slide, in this case, the `a` element.

This seems to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mySlideShow').cycle({
    log: false,
    fx: 'fade',
    slides: ">a",
    caption: '.cycle-caption',
    captionTemplate: "{{target}}",
    pauseOnHover: true,
  });
})
```

```css
.slide-gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 790px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.slide-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cycle-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide-gallery">
  <div class="mySlideShow">

    <a target="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
    </a>
    <a target="This is my caption....">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
    </a>
    <a target="bla.....">
      <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to work with custom attributes, that is why I've used `target`. If you don't wrap your images in `a` elements, you could use the image's `alt` attribute, that will be more appropriate.